# Searching for vowels in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
str = "Find the vowels in this string or else I'll date your sister"
```

I am looking to count the number of vowels in a string and I believe I have achieved this, but I have done it by appending the each letter to an array and taking the length of the array. What's a more common way to do this. Maybe with +=?

```
str.chars.to_a.each do |i|
    if i =~ /[aeiou]/ 
        x.push(i)
    end
end
x.length
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *count* the vowels, why not use [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-count):

```
str.chars.count {|c| c =~ /[aeiou]/i }
```

Comment: It frequently happens on SO that the best answer is not the accepted answer, and this is one of those cases.

Comment: Just an explanation: The asker has changed zer mind and accepted this answer after I wrote the comment. The key is to use `#count` when you mean to count. I discovered that `#count` is also defined on `String` and added one more answer later.

Answer (score 6):

But here is even better answer =). It turns out that we have a `String#count` method:

```
str.downcase.count 'aeiou'
#=> 17
```

Comment: I like yours.. as the problem is solved with the string without converting it to an array.

Answer (score 3):

Use `scan`

```
"Find the vowels in this string or else I'll date your sister".scan(/[aeiou]/i).length
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to:

```
str.chars.to_a
```

In fact, str.chars already is a Array

```
> String.new.chars.class
 => Array
```

Refactoring a little

```
str.chars.each{|i| i =~ /[aeiou]/ ? x : nil}
x.length
```

But maybe an alternative for the best solution could be:

```
a.chars.map{|x| x if x.match(/[aeiouAEIOU]/)}.join.size
```

You should check the map block because you could perform something useful inside, as an alternative just for the count block.

without doubt best solution for count vowel inside string using block:

```
str.chars.count {|c| c =~ /[aeiou]/i }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are shorter incarnations.

```
$ irb
>> "Find the vowels in this string or else I'll date your sister".gsub(/[^aeiou]/i, '').length
=> 17
```

Comment: You can add `.length` to get the count of vowels, since that's what the question was asking for.

Comment: Whoops, missed that.  Here we go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that use [String#tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
str = "Find the vowels in this string or else I'll date your sister"

str.size - str.tr('aeiouAEIOU','').size #=> 17
```

or

```
str.size - str.downcase.tr('aeiou','').size #=> 17
```